# Move file from src to dest using HTML FIleSystem API

Tags: angularjs, html, typescript, electron, html5-filesystem

This is a very simple question, but is giving me a lot of trouble. I want to move a file from origin to destination in my local file system.

I'm using HTML5 FileSystem API. This is my code:

```
// Note: The file system has been prefixed as of Google Chrome 12:
window.requestFileSystem = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;

// window.requestFileSystem(type, size, successCallback, opt_errorCallback)

window.requestFileSystem(window.TEMPORARY, 1024 * 1024, (fs) => {
            this.copyResouce(fs.root, "/home/user/Escritorio/img.png", this.AppConfig.DEFAULT_RESOURCE_PATH + "img/");
        }, this.errorHandler);

private copyResouce(cwd, src, dest) {
       cwd.getFile(src, {}, (fileEntry) => {
             cwd.getDirectory(dest, {}, (dirEntry) => {
                    fileEntry.copyTo(dirEntry);
                });
             }, this.errorHandler);
        }
```

But I'm getting **NOT_FOUND_ERR** - A requested file or directory could not be found at the time an operation was processed.

I'm using an stack with AngularJS + Typescript in an Electron App.

Any idea?

Cheers,
Abel

Comment: Not sure if you can use node-modules (fs) but passing filesystem path to window.requestLocalFilesystemURL(fs.root, resolve, reject) api worked for me all times with no permission, storage or security issues which usually occurs when using webkit storage.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Chrome for your test ?
please read http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webapps/2014AprJun/0010.html
This API was deprecated by W3C and never implement in all navigator but chrome.

The available files are in the sandbox too. Are you sure your file is in it ?

Answer (score 0):

Electron will use the window.requestFileSystem from line 1 but you in line 2, you are passing the webkit based path (window.temporary). I think you should pass the local filesystem root path instead. I think you can add the `fs` node-module and instead of window.temporary, pass fs.root (root is specific to platform, in electron it's `file:///temporary/` i think) and it will work in most case.